# Java EE different authentication mechanism for pages and services

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-8

I have a Java EE aplication that uses @CustomFormAuthenrticationMechanismDefinition and is working correctly: when a user that is not logged in tries to access a url, it is redirected to the login page.

I added a web service to the application, but when I consume it, I receive the login page as the response instead of the web service response.

Is there a way to use @CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition for the web pages and @BasicAuthenticationMechanismDefinition for the web services?

Or is there a better way to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check section 13.8 of [Servlet specification](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/servlet-3_1-final.pdf?AuthParam=1599046145_fe7fb8df81c744a6ac2bc3372b76e1be)? Ideally, you just have to define two security-constraints: one for your simple web area, another to your web services, each one with the proper authentication mechanism. As I've never tried this approach, I won't answer. Please report your results, though.

Comment: Section 13.8 is about athorization, but my problem is before that, in the athentication (section 13.6). In the specification I couldn't find anything about using two authentiation mechanisms. Here is a link to the [Servlet specification](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-3.1/Final/servlet-3_1-final.pdf) that doesn't needs login.